# JPA Qyery to find records between a range

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have 1 million records in a table want to fetch 1000 records at time using EJB3.1(JPA QUERY) but not get any good method do it, LIMIT is unexpected token for JPA. so kindly suggest me a way to fetch limited records on a method call. I used `setFirstRsult(count)` and `setMaxResult(count+1000)` but on next method call firstResult Set starting from 0 every time rather of starting from 1001 ,to update setFirstResult count I am maintaining counter.but still doesn't get any solution.

```
String query = "select a from CourseMasterBo a";
        List<CourseMasterBo> list = new ArrayList<CourseMasterBo>();
         list = manager.createQuery(query).setFirstResult(4).setMaxResults(8).getResultList();
         logger.info("list size--------"+list.size());   


 I should get 4 as size of list but i am getting 8 ,starting from intial to 8th records in db.
below is my query and answer---->
17:39:47,435 INFO  [com.infinite.gndu.academicDtos.AcademicYear] list size--------8
```

Comment: Yes, sir i maintaining counter instead of that setFirstResult starting from 0 every time , have you ever implemented , i am not getting right result, if you know how to do it please share code with me

Comment: Show some code, what have you done so far?

Comment: Hey Ean I have posted my code below please have look and correct me

Comment: Your code should be posted inthe QUESTION, not as an answer. Edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the answer if you want to fetch only 100 records than set the setMaxResult(100) and don't change the setMaxResult value and Keep on changing the setFristResult(), like 0.101,100 always give you 100 result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//....
int queryResultSize = 1000000;

public List getResultQuery(queryResultSize){
    String SQL_QUERY = "SELECT ...."; // your query
    List resultList = new ArrayList(); // Add the specific type of the result

    for(int i = 0; i < queryResultSize; i++){
        resultList.addAll(entityManager.createQuery(SQL_QUERY).setParameter(arg0,arg1).
            setFirstRsult(i).setMaxResults(1000 + i).getResultList());
    }

    return resultList;
}
```