# setFirstResult() and Limit Failing in Ejb3.1

Tags: mysql, jpa, ejb-3.1

I have 10000 records in database i want to fetch 100 record first time next 100 record 2nd time and so on. I'm using `setFirstResult()` and `maxResult()`. I'm  maintaining a counter to update set first result offset `setFirstResult(count)` is always started from first index whatever value you put inside it, it start from 0.

```
List<StudentBo> bos=manager.createNamedQuery("getAllApplicantForRegistration")
                   .setParameter("batch",dto.getBatch())
                   .setFirstResult(count)
                   .setMaxResult(lastIndex).getResultList();
```

Comment: Yes I am getting the Same problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971483/jpa-qyery-to-find-records-between-a-range?noredirect=1#comment42482794_26971483 check the link the setfirst result always showing value from 0.

Comment: i have already printted logger of count before setFirstResult(count).count value is changing every time but setFirstResult(count) started from 0

Comment: It's unclear how you are initializing values, but I think you are providing incorrect values. 'MaxResult' should be 100 always & 'FirstResult' should be changing like 0,101,201... something like this.

Comment: Thanks Nayan i was increasing both firstResult and maxResult.now i have got a solution thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

setFirstResult  will incease every time while setMaxResult will be static.